# New (2022) Azure SDK .net - Get private IP address of VM primary network interface

Tags: azure-sdk-.net

by following the instructions provided here [Quickstart Tutorial - Resource Management](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/doc/dev/mgmt_quickstart.md),
I am trying to find a way to get the private IP address of a VM but it looks like the VirtualMachineResource does not expose any related property.

With the old SDK it was pretty straight forward but with the new SDK it does not seem possible. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

thanks for the suggestions. I had to dig into the properties of the VirtualMachineResource class and in the end I got it. Here a code snippet. For simplicity's sake I am assuming that the VM has only one network interface, which has only one IP configuration.

```
var subscriptionId = "...";
var resourcegroup = "...";
var vmName = "...";
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
var subscriptionIdentifier = SubscriptionResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId);
SubscriptionResource subscription = client.GetSubscriptionResource(subscriptionIdentifier);
var rg = subscription.GetResourceGroup(resourcegroup);
var vm = rg.Value.GetVirtualMachine(vmName);
var networkInterfaceReference = vm.Value.Data.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Single();
var networkInterfaceResource = client.GetNetworkInterfaceResource(new ResourceIdentifier(networkInterfaceReference.Id));
var privateIpAddress = networkInterfaceResource.GetNetworkInterfaceIPConfigurations().Single().Data.PrivateIPAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

For virtual machines a private IP address or addresses are assigned to one or more network interfaces.

> VirtualMachineResource does not expose any related property.

Yes, Virtual Machine Resources does not provide any related property. The private IP address of virtual machine scale set instances cannot be obtained. The network interfaces of virtual machine scale sets are not Azure resources and cannot be obtained.

1. You can use the **[REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/network-interface-ip-configurations/get)** to achieve.

   Refer to [Get all azure VM's with all their Private and Public IP's](https://mihai-albert.com/2020/10/01/get-the-list-of-all-azure-vms-with-all-their-private-and-public-ips/)

> Get private IP address of VM primary network interface

2. To get the Private IP address you can use the **PrimaryIPConfiguration** and **PrimaryPrivateIP** properties.

[image]

Refer [Latest Azure SDK for .NET - VMSS Network Interface Properties and Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.network.fluent.ivirtualmachinescalesetnetworkinterface?view=azure-dotnet)